# Unable to load local HTML file inside WebView in Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift2, xcode7, wkwebview

I have a local `HTML` (static content and no links inside) file that needs to be loaded inside a Web View. I have used `UIWebView` to load it but after upgrading to Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7 the existing implementation crashes at the line presentViewController where we try to present the View Controller that has the web view inside but previously it was working. It seems the issue because of `WebKit` introduction but it should not affect the existing implementation right. So any one can help me or suggest me the best way to go?
The project targets iOS 8 and above (iPad only).
this is the code that was working

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html")   
let prepareRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: path!)  
self.webView.loadRequest(prepareRequest)
```

Thanks

```
Crash Report      
1   0x8707b09 StartWebThread()                                  
2   0x524d6b0 __pthread_once_handler     
3   0x523eebe _os_once     
4   0x524d65f pthread_once    
5   0x870789e WebThreadEnable     
6   0x75ce14a +[WebView(WebPrivate) enableWebThread]     
7   0x75cad90 WebKitInitialize        
8   0x2822a30 ___UIApplicationLoadWebKit_block_invoke      
9   0x4f0abef _dispatch_client_callout       
10  0x4ef4a92 dispatch_once_f       
11  0x4ef4922 dispatch_once       
12  0x2822940 _UIApplicationLoadWebKit        
13  0x4083461 _class_initialize          
14  0x408bfe5 lookUpImpOrForward           
15  0x408be8d _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3          
16  0x409612f objc_msgSend         
17  0x2cef77a UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue          
18  0x2cef9b0 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue            
19  0x2cef4c3 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]        
20  0x289480c -[UIView initWithCoder:]        
21  0x28be337 -[UIScrollView initWithCoder:]         
22  0x2cef7ae UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue           
23  0x2cef4c3 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]         
24  0x2b6cbca -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]       
25  0x2cef7ae UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue        
26  0x2cef9b0 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue        
27  0x2cef4c3 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
28  0x2b6be80 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]        
29  0x29860d4 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:]        
30  0x298686b -[UIViewController loadView]         
31  0x2986a9f -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on a new project and it doesn't crash for me. Did you disable App Transport Security when you upgraded to Xcode7?

Add this to your plist if you haven't disabled it yet.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Yes, I have added the plist code and still I am getting crash. Added the crash report to the main question

Comment: You don't need `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` for loading files. It is only relevant for network requests.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Use the loadHTMLString:baseURL: method to begin loading local HTML files or the loadRequest: method to begin loading web content.

Maybe they have changed something for security reasons:

> To help you avoid being vulnerable to security attacks, be sure to use this method to load local HTML files; don’t use loadRequest:

I use loadHTMLString:baseURL: and works like a charm. It needs a string, so you should get the content of the html file and store it in a String.

Try this way and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following new and iOS9-Only API:

> `func loadFileURL(_ URL: NSURL,
>       allowingReadAccessToURL readAccessURL: NSURL) -> WKNavigation?`

The second `NSURL` should point to a directory if your `index.html` needs to load resources from your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself. When we use the dispatch_sync to open up pop over we can avoid the crash and it works for me.

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
   self.presentViewController(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }